# How to create a flip book/page?

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, actionscript

I need to create a flip book/page application. I have seen flash created flip page, can it be done in any other languages, e.g. jquery or javascript? And also, what are some concepts that I am required to have in mind/knowledge on for creating a flip book?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by "flip book", can you elaborate on this?

If you mean just a digital book, that you can turn the pages of, then I would surgest looking into this [AS3 page-flip engine](http://megazine.mightypirates.de/?c=home&l=en). And here is a list of good (mostly commercial) [examples](http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/flip-a-page-with-these-flash-page-flippers/)

***EDIT**** - Not to sure why you would want to create this from scratch, as there are a ton of well made Page-flip libraries out there that are really nicely build, and are either free, or really cheep. Most of the time they are customizable too.

That said, I think they are probably all using a combination of the following:

- **Preloaded pages** - movieclip with either an image or
  other graphics preloaded into it
- **Gradients** - to give the illusion of a 3d page that is "turning"
- **Trigonometry** - for dragging effect. To angle the page towards mouse
- **Masks** - to get the page folding effect, when the user start to drag the page, the next page is loaded over the top. Both these page have been masked off based on the users mouse position.

Also the Page-flip engine I linked to above ([MegaZine](http://megazine.mightypirates.de/)), is open-source. So if you where really keen, then you could dive into there source code and take a look for yourself.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Yup, digital book is what i am looking for. A great list of page-flip examples, I will look through. Thanks.

Comment: Would you have any references on how to create them out of scratch? Thanks.

Comment: I volunteer with a non-profit group and most services require $15-25(USD)/month. Over time that adds up. Making something from scratch would by a developer (me) willing to set it up for free just helps their funds go towards the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something simple, and don't want to delve into codes, try out pressmo: http://pressmo.com/example3/1

It works faster on slower computers than most of other similar services and what's important you keep your flipbook on your own computer/web server (as online flash or offline executable).
To create a flip page you have to upload your content as a PDF file (which can be easily obtained from Word or Open Office).

Usually a good solution for flipbooks is to keep the number of your pages even, otherside the user will not have the possibility to turn the last site. All pages should be similar size also.