# Flip Book Effect AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, effect, flip

i m trying to develop a bb playbook app. how can i make a flip book effect with as3? i need to have 10 images(pages) to flip :S can anybody help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flip+book

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a flip book/page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720561/how-to-create-a-flip-book-page)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't a simple effect to create from scratch. If you do do it from scratch it will require the combination of scripted Tweens, masked clips and transformations.

I would recommended, depending on your experience level, to either buy a flip book component from www.flashden.com or start building one and when you get stuck ask a specific question here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [flip book maker](http://flippingbook.com/online-flipbook/) FlippingBook. Check out how they do it.